# Obtener valores de los checkboxes seleccionados en controlador ASP.NET Core C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Tengo una aplicación web en ASP.NET Core y necesito poder pasar los valores de los checkboxes seleccionados de la vista al controlador. Lo estoy haciendo mediante el uso de html.checkboxesfor para poder pasarlo con el modelo pero cuando lo devuelvo a la función me devuelve siempre ambas listas vacías.  No quiero hacerlo mediante JQuery, quiero poder pasarlo usando el formulario. No encuentro el error que estoy comentiendo.

Este es el modelo:

```
 public class ProdMMIAsignacion {

    public ProdMMIAsignacion() {
      this.ProductosAsignados = new List<ProductosAsignados>();
      this.ProductosNoAsignados = new List<ProductosNoAsignados>();
    }
    public List<ProductosAsignados> ProductosAsignados { get; set; }
    public List<ProductosNoAsignados> ProductosNoAsignados { get; set; }
    public string TipoMMI { get; set; }

  }
```

Los dos modelos interiores ProductosAsignados y ProductosNoAsignados:

```
 public class ProductosAsignados {

    public ProductosAsignados() {
      this.isChecked = false; 
    }
    public string IdNivel5Rentabilidad { get; set; }
    public bool isChecked { get; set; }


  }

 public class ProductosNoAsignados {

    public ProductosNoAsignados() {
      isCheckedNo = false;
    }
    public string IdNivel5Rentabilidad { get; set; }
    public bool isCheckedNo { get; set; }

  }
```

Este es el código de la vista:

```
@model ETEKOST.Models.ProdMMIAsignacion
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Productos Asociados a Tipos MMI";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - ETEKOST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/pantallas.css" />


    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/TiposMMI/AsignacionProductosMMI.js"></script>


</head>
<body>


    <h2 class="titulo_secundario">PRODUCTOS ASOCIADOS A TIPOS MMI</h2>

    <hr class="solid" />

    <div class="asignaciones_buscar">
       <label>Tipo MMI o Descripción (*):</label>
       <input type="text" name="nombre" id="tipo">
       <button id="buscarTipo">Buscar</button>
    </div>

    <div>
       <p style="color:#F8F6F1">Separador</p>
       <hr class="solid" />
    </div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Asignacion_prev", "TiposMMI", FormMethod.Post))
    {

        
    
        <div class="asignacion" id="productos">

            <div style="display: none">
                <label>Producto seleccionado: </label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="TipoMMI" />
            </div>

            <div class="asignacion_sub_origen">
                <label>Productos no asignados:</label>

                <div class="bus_asignacion">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Barra de búsqueda">
                </div>


                <div id="origen" class="lista-asignacion">

                    @foreach (var ori in Model.ProductosNoAsignados)
                    {
                        <div>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => ori.isCheckedNo)
                            <label>@ori.IdNivel5Rentabilidad</label>

                        </div>
                     }

              


                </div>

            </div>

            
            <div class="asignacion_sub_bot">

                <button id="pasar_der" class="botones_asignaciones">→</button>

                <button id="pasar_izq" class="botones_asignaciones">←</button>

            </div>


            <div class="asignacion_sub_destino">
                <label>Productos asignados:</label>


                <div id="destino" class="lista-asignacion">
                    @foreach (var des in Model.ProductosAsignados)
                     {
                        <div>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => des.isChecked)
                            <label>@des.IdNivel5Rentabilidad</label>

                        </div>  
                    }



                </div>

            </div>


        </div>



        <div class="botones">

            <input type="submit" class="boton_aceptar" value="Previsualizar">
        </div>
        
     }


</body>

</html>
```

Y adjunto pantallazo del controlador y el resultado que me devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría obtener los valores que he seleccionado sin utilizar **jquery**?